# Should I help my company in getting more business when they rejected my salary increase and promotion?

Tags: manager, clients, teamleader

I am a very helpful person and love to help out whenever asked to. I am leading a team of half a dozen people and work for Company A through Company B, which is my real employer.

Things have been going well and smooth but I just do not get any appreciation for my work. I do not have a direct boss as such but a nominal manager who I report to. I also work with the Client service manager who deals with all the accounts in the area, including company A that I work for.

Yesterday we had an internal meeting (company B people) and they asked me if I can help get more business from the client. I had helped set up a meeting a few months ago but there has been no follow up on that by our client services manager nor company A.

While all this makes sense, another side issue is related. I have raised concerns with my company (Company B - actual employer) where I asked to review my compensation or title. I am going from pole to pole but no one has the time to address this issue adequately. But just last week I brought up my point in a presentation and the presenter set up a meeting with the concerned person to address the issue after realizing that my concerns are legit. In that meeting, I got the same answer: my pay will not be increased just because they do not have the 'budget' nor my title will be changed. With all this inflation, I did not receive any raise in the past 2 years even had 4/5 ratings. My colleagues I know of are getting much more than I am. My manager said in the meeting that I agreed to this pay when I was hired (3 years ago)- which was the excuse.

My question is, should I help my company B get more business from company A, after considering that they denied raising my salary or elevate my position. If they can say I agreed to this salary 3 years ago, can I say "this is nowhere mentioned in my job description that I will help them get more business". My take is that this is client services manager job. If he is not following up on his own, why should I help, considering they are not giving me a raise? What is the ethical and right thing to do here. Why not the client services manager uses his own direct links to peopl get more business, why he has to rely on me (and kind of blaming me also in the process). I asked for either a promotion or a change in title, both were rejected. Besides, I am not kept in the loop when any changes are made in my team. I am not given the opportunity to rate my team at the end of the year, which seems unfair and wrong. I highlighted those issues along with my compensation concerns but none of them were addressed adequately. I was simply told, they will keep a note of it.

I do want to mention that other than this, I do not have any other issues in the job. I do not have extra workload and no one bothers me as such and everything else is going smoothly which is a big for me.

I am also aware that if I help them out, this will give me a an opportunity to work with senior people which is good for me but I still want to know should I help in the scenario or ignore?

### Edited:

I have edited the above question with some more context. To see the original question, please check the history of the question. Outside SE, one help I got said, it is not my job to get them more business, it is Client Services Manager job and he gets all the bonus by signing in more work, while I get nothing. On a side note, I did reach out to my various managers in Company A and asked if we can engage company B in more areas. That is not a problem for me, but it is heartening that, with all sincerity and hard word, the company ignores your pay and benefits. Of course, I do not work hard for a salary increase, I do it as part of my job, basically who I am.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere right, I can just ignore those requests from them but it would not be an ethical thing to do (at least for me). I don't have any direct manager as such, so I don't have to refuse it to anybody. I agree, finding a new job seems like the only good alternative for me since my salary is not that great.

Comment: Btw I just engaged with my managers to give my company B more business. But seems like I will have to find a higher paying job elsewhere.

Comment: If I understand correctly, company B asked you to attempt to convince company A to give them more business. To that end, you set up a meeting with the appropriate people from company B but nothing came of it. What exactly is your current quandary? Are you asking if you should keep pushing despite the apparent lack of interest or if it’s okay to let it go?

Comment: @AffableAmbler company B (my real employer) is not increasing my pay, even though I have a low salary compared to colleagues and even after I am getting 4/5 ratings each year. As I do not have a direct boss, I have been going from pole to pole to find out who will address my issue. Finally I talked to the right person and he said he does not have budget. My question is, if they can't review my salary, why should I go above and beyond and get them more business. Manager said, I agreed to this salary 3 years ago so I can say "getting more business is not in my job description when I signed up"?

Answer (score 5):

Taking offense decreases the odds of your getting either raise or promotion in the future. Either work to earn those (start by asking your manager what they would have to see from you to justify that), or accept that you didn't earn them and decide whether that means you should leave.

Staying while deliberately not doing your best hurts you as much as them. Probably more.

Answer (score 4):

> I got the same answer that my pay will not be increased just because we do not have the 'budget' neither title will change.

I'm afraid that's all you need to know. You are not getting a raise and more money in the future are also not likely. You will either have to make your peace with that or start looking for a new job.

> I still want to know should I help in the scenario or ignore?

If I were you I would start looking for a new job starting right now. In the meantime continue to do your job well. I probably wouldn't do a whole lot of unpaid overtime, but intentionally performing below your capabilities seems doesn't help anyone. You can still feel good about a job well done even if it's underpaid.

Once you have a new job, hand in your resignation, serve your notice period and move on to better things.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with others saying you should continue doing your best, and at most look for another job in your free time. If your employer is refusing to raise your salary at least to cover inflation, then they are effectively cutting your pay. Assuming you're in the USA or a country facing similar inflation, then your salary has been reduced in value by about 20% since you started three years ago. Don't fall for the nonsense idea that you owe your employer your very best performance and every ounce of your talent. Pay is supposed to represent the value you create for the company. If they won't pay you more, then don't create more value for them. It's that simple.

If it were me, I'd flat out refuse and tell them why: your salary has effectively gone down 20% from when you started (get a good cite for this for your exact location), and you're not willing to take on additional responsibilities without being compensated for them, and you're certainly not going to do it while you're being paid much less than you originally agreed.

This isn't likely to backfire seriously. Chances are they can't replace you with somebody new for your same salary. Even if they could find someone with your same skills willing to work for your current pay, it's very expensive to hire and onboard new employees. It's not going to cost you a raise or promotion, because they've already made it clear that will never happen. Quit letting them take advantage of you. They don't have the leverage they pretend they do.

And yes, you should move on to somewhere that'll recognize and compensate you fairly.  I hope you enjoy laughing at your employer when they're suddenly able to offer you a raise when you hand in your notice.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. Right, my employer is not in a position to fire me and even if I flat out deny everything, even then they can't fire me. Which bring up the point of job security that I have. Yes, my pay has affectively decreased in the past 2 years considering the inflation. The only other upside is workload is not that high and I have flexible schedule (home/office). I do think moving out would be right call when the time comes.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been going above and beyond in the hopes of getting a raise and you've been denied, it is rational for you to go back to the bare minimum. Whilst I don't endorse what is now termed 'Quiet Quitting' - this is a strategy. As others have mentioned this can backfire and is generally considered to be unprofessional - but it is rational.

The best strategy though would be to look elsewhere. I once stayed at a job I was 'over' for longer than I should have (it took me took long to realise I was over it) and in the last few months whilst I was job hunting, my performance suffered to the point I was looking down the barrel of a PIP.

Comment: Yes, I have been going above and beyond to make the project go smoothly. I am the key person in the project without me nothing will work. Other then no raise/no promotion, things are going well though since I do not have a direct boss and have no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

The theory: There is **loyalty** and there is the **market principle**. People tend to get a pay raise on the principles of economics, in specific the labour market situation.

##### The Economics

If it is likely that a person could leave a company and that would effectively create costs higher (new hire, higher salary, wait times, time-to-productivity, etc..) than a pay raise, than it is a logical economic decision to provide a pay raise. Most companies have systems in place (yearly) of automatic pay raise to strategically retain the workforce.

If a person does not receive a pay raise this is due to some reasons, first it would cause equal or less costs to not raise the salary. Second, the persons performance is not valued (eg. not visible). Third, despite all logic the company cannot spend money (insufficient cash flow or anti economic politics).

##### Loyalty and Trust

There is a widely accepted and praised logical fallacy in the labour market, that loyalty and trust only works into one direction. From the employee to the employer. When in reality loyalty and trust is a bilateral relationship.

Some companies expect employees to trust and being loyal unconditionally (at the same time not providing a pay raise), however in the other direction employees have to earn their trust and loyalty (over years).

This raises the question if employees unconditionally shall trust and be loyal to companies, which do *not* unconditionally trust them and being loyal to them in return?

##### Your Situation is a Triangle

You are situated in an economic triangle of company A, company B and the very yourself. Choose wisely where your loyalty and trust lies and where your work is seen and valued.

##### My Opinion

It is my opinion that you should try to raise the visibility of the value of your work equally at both companies, alongside testing yourself and your value on the labour market frequently (interviews, salary negotiations). This will help you understand which actions to take.

So long, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for bringing some great eye-opening points, such as loyalty should be seen from both sides, not one and replacement itself can be costly which is in my case. My employer is not a position to ask me to simply leave, they are dependent on me. If I am being replaced, I would need at least a month to train the new guy-------Yes, I raised my visility issues. For example the team I manage is not rated by me but rated by so called manager who does not work with them. How in the world he knows who is doing good? The organization accepted these flaws but said it will stay the same.